# How to use same token until expires?

Tags: javascript, typescript, axios, playwright, react-fullstack

In the code below, I will call LoginAPI for authorization and writes token as a state(Login.e2e.ts ).By the way using axios interceptors.request in my axios.ts file.

**My question is;**

If I use below code logic, when I send request with customAxios in my project,everytime `await LoginAPI.API.Signin.run()` will run for every API request. Soon,I can have 100 API call. I don t want run every time `await LoginAPI.API.Signin.run()`,because I can take 429 error.

**The new logic should be like this;**

I want to take a token first and then use it until it expires. If the token expired then send a new request and get a new token. How can do this using JavaScript or TypeScript?

**This is my Login.e2e.ts file**

```
import api from "api/core"
import { expect } from "@playwright/test";

export const LoginAPI = {

  States: {
    token: {} as string
  },

  API: {
    Signin: {
      notes: "user login",
      run: async () => {
        let res: any = await api.test.LoginPost(process.env.NAME, process.env.PASS)
        LoginAPI.States.token = res.data.token
        expect(res.status).toBe(200)
      },
    },

  },
};
```

**This is my axios.ts file**

```
import axios from "axios";
import { LoginAPI } from "../playwright/tests/login/login.api";

const customAxios = axios.create({
    baseURL: process.env.ENV === '1' ? "https://test1" : process.env.ENV === '2' ? "https://test2" : "https://test3",
});


customAxios.interceptors.request.use(
    async (config) => {
       await LoginAPI.API.Signin.run()
        if (config.headers) {
            config.headers['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${LoginAPI.States.token}`;
            return config;
        }
        return config;
    },
    (error) => {
        Promise.reject(error);
    }
);
export default customAxios
```

take a token first and then use it until it expires. If the token expired then send a new request and get a new token.The above code should be changed the this logic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to log in once and get cookies from the browser.context() and save them as JSON file then use this cookie state/session for the rest of the test. That way you won't have to log in every time for new tests or test suites.

More information using `storageState(options)` [here](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-browsercontext#browser-context-storage-state) in official docs.

Example of using `storageState(options)` in your global setup and teardown [here](https://playwright.dev/docs/test-advanced#global-setup-and-teardown) in official docs.